# Loading Assembly Dynamically while executing string C# code

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, reference

I am executing C# code dynamically by using "CSharpCodeProvider" then compile the code and invoke the method. I need to include a certain DLL files to the compiler in order to call classes from that DLL. I am using the method:

```
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(the path of the DLL File);
```

But when invoking the method, I get an error :

```
Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But when I just include the DLL from Project>References>Add Reference , the code invoked withed any error. Can anyone tell me how to add the reference dynamically on run-time to avoid that error?

Here is the code :

```
CSharpCodeProvider Code = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler icc = Code.CreateCompiler();
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.data.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.windows.forms.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"D:\AnalogClockControl.dll");
cp.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
sb.Append("using System;\n");
sb.Append("using System.Data;\n");
sb.Append("using System.Windows.Forms;\n");
sb.Append("namespace CSCodeEvaler{ \n");
sb.Append("public class CSCodeEvaler{ \n");
sb.Append("public void test(){AnalogClockControl.AnalogClock _AnalogClock= new AnalogClockControl.AnalogClock();}\n");
sb.Append("} \n");
sb.Append("}\n");
CompilerResults cr = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sb.ToString());
if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
{
   return  ; //"ERROR: " + cr.Errors[0].ErrorText
}
System.Reflection.Assembly a = cr.CompiledAssembly;
object o = a.CreateInstance("CSCodeEvaler.CSCodeEvaler");
Type t = o.GetType();
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("test"); 
object j = mi.Invoke(o, new object[] {}); // Here where I get the exception
```

Comment: Maybe you're writing the wrong path. Could you show us your code?

Comment: My guess would be there's a dependency problem.  Try checking the "Assembly loader exception" for more info.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response.
Eve: the path is correct, otherwise the error won't be gone if I added the DLL manually. I will post the code in a minute ..
dbaseman: Can you please tell me from where I can find the Assembly loader exception ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add a `using` statament for `AnalogClockControl` namespace

```
sb.Append("using AnalogClockControl;\n"); // whatever the namespace is
```

**EDIT: never mind, that should not compile at all if it was required.**

Comment: Adding this line wont do anything because when I am defining the instance, I am including the full class name 
AnalogClockControl.AnalogClock _AnalogClock= new AnalogClockControl.AnalogClock();
Anyway, I tried to add this line and I still have the same error.